# Is there a global base Uri factory?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly, hateoas

I need to get at the baseUri, I'm familliar with this

```
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;
```

my problem is I need the baseUri in a piece of code I can't Inject into, (a sub object of an entity). I could pass `uriInfo` or the builder down but that doesn't seem ideal, as most of the objects have no business knowing about it. The end goal is HATEOAS URI's in my JSON responses, but I don't need it to be a JAX-RS specific solution, I figure if I can just get at the Base URI either in my jackson converters, or entities, I can create the `URIBuilder` from there.

Answer (score 0):

The `UriInfo` is managed by the JAX-RS implementation and AFAIK, you cannot actually inject it in other places of your code (it's no a CDI bean). If your goal is to implement HATEOAS, you could probably write your own MessageBodyWriter which will be responsible for unmarshalling your entity objects graph into a JSON response and in which you can inject this `UriInfo`.

HTH.

Comment: isn't MessageBodyWriter what Jackson does? hand serializing every part of all of my objects sounds unpleasant, and error prone. even if it was a CDI bean that wouldn't help because you can't Inject into entities... I'm not sure there's a jax-rs level solution...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Minutes after I wrote all this I found Chapter 12. Declarative Hyperlinking in the Jersey 2.13 spec. It's still "under development and experimental" but looks like it solves this problem much more elegantly. All the code in the original post can be replaced by this...

```
public class Pie {

  private String name;

  Pie(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @InjectLink(value="pies/{name}", style=Style.ABSOLUTE)
  public URI url;
}
```

If you need to send arbitrary data to a Jackson serializer then the solution below is still valid.

**ORIGINAL** I had the same issue. Specifically I wanted my resources to contain just their id (the thing at the end of their URI) and find a way to generate the complete URI using UriInfo only when Jackson generates the JSON. I wanted to avoid solutions where I had to either create new cover objects on my resources for each request, or insert the UriInfo into each resource before it was serialized.

It turns out that as of Jackson 2.3 there is a very nice way to do this. Jackson supports a class called ObjectWriterInjector. Using its static set method you can provide your own instance of an ObjectWriterModifier once per request. That instance can be created and set in your Jersey resource method where UriInfo is available. Before Jackson writes out JSON it calls your ObjectWriterModifier giving you a chance to tweak the ObjectWriter it will use. In this case, you can use the withAttribute method to attach UriInfo to the ObjectWriter.

So what good is an attribute on the ObjectWriter? It turns out that those attributes are available through the SerializerProvider parameter in the serialize method of a JsonSerializer implementation. In my case I only wanted to modify one field so I used @JsonSerialize on the getter. In the serialize method I then call the SerializerProvider parameter's getAttribute method to retrieve the UriInfo and then use it to construct the complete URI.

This methodology should work in any case where you want to push information down to a Jackson serializer.

Simple Jersey resource...

```
@Path("/pies")
public class Pies {

    static List<Pie> pies;

    static 
    {
        pies = new ArrayList<Pie>();
        pies.add(new Pie("apple"));
        pies.add(new Pie("pumpkin"));
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Pie> getPies(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        // This is the good stuff!!!!
        ObjectWriterInjector.set(new ObjectWriterPlusUriInfo(uriInfo));

        // Notice I don't have to anything to the objects in the Pies list 
        return pies;
    }
}
```

The class that tweaks the ObjectWriter...

```
class ObjectWriterPlusUriInfo extends ObjectWriterModifier {

private UriInfo uriInfo;

ObjectWriterPlusUriInfo(UriInfo uriInfo) {
    this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
}

@Override
public ObjectWriter modify(EndpointConfigBase<?> endpoint,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> responseHeaders, Object value,
        ObjectWriter ow, JsonGenerator gen) throws IOException {
    // Adding the UriInfo attribute
    return ow.withAttribute("JerseyUriInfo", uriInfo);
    }
}
```

The Pie class with Jackson annotations...

```
public class Pie {

private String name;

Pie(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@JsonProperty(value="url")
@JsonSerialize(using=JacksonIdToUrlSerializer.class)
public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
}
```

Serializer...

```
public class JacksonIdToUrlSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String>{

@Override
public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    UriInfo uriInfo = (UriInfo)provider.getAttribute("JerseyUriInfo");
    jgen.writeString(uriInfo.getRequestUriBuilder().path(value).build().toString());
    }
}
```

A GET of...

```
http://localhost:8080/service/api/pies...
```

Produces...

```
[
  {
  url: "http://localhost:8080/service/api/pies/apple"
  },
  {
  url: "http://localhost:8080/service/api/pies/pumpkin"
  }
]
```

A GET of...

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/service/api/pies...
```

Produces...

```
[
  {
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/service/api/pies/apple"
  },
  {
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/service/api/pies/pumpkin"
  }
]
```

Note that the ObjectWriterInjector uses a Thread Local variable internally so using that more generic method to pass data down on a per request basis seems equally valid.